# Many conditions, reducing code size

Tags: c, if-statement, coding-style

Is there any other good solution than using if branch inside if to examine and meet all required conditions? It looks a little bit big in code to write like this, I want to reduce code size, but to suit my needs.

```
if(a>0 && b>0 && c>0) 
{
    if(a==d && b==e && c==f)
    {
         if(a<FIELD_HEIGHT && b<FIELD_WIDTH)
         {
             if(true) 
             {

             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is to reduce *nesting*, not code size (which kind of implies less machine code being generated by the compiler). And the answer very much depends on what happens inside the `if` statement blocks, only more `if` statements or something else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I need to avoid so much if statements if its possible. But in my case I have 3 different groups which checks different things, and when I wrote all of them it looks big to me, thats why I want to reduce code size.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20reduce%20if%20else%20statements

Comment: Also a bit of math might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: Are those varibales `signed` or `unsigned`? Or less specific how are they defined?

Comment: @alk Thats just an example, look them as unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use logical AND operator (`&&`):

```
if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3) {
  // action
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if (cond1) {
  if (cond2) {
    if (cond3) {
      // action
    }
  }
}
```

That is useful as long as you don't need an `else` clause specific to any of those conditions.

Conditions will be evaulated from the left, so if `cond1` will be `false`, `cond2` and `cond3` won't get evaluated.

---

**EDIT**: If you have many conditions that need to be true in order to take an action, and you're concerned with code readability, I'd group them in a boolean variables first, i.e.:

```
int isCar = has4Wheels && hasBreaks && hasEngine;
int isASportsCar = hasLargeEngine && hasLowSuspension && hasManualControls;
int isFerrari = isV12 && isRed && hasANiceLogo;

if (isCar && isASportsCar && isFerrari) {
  // action
}
```

Example might be dumb, but you get the point.

Comment: "*Dump*"? No, it's true! I'd upvoted this just again for the nice example in your edit ...! :-)

Comment: @alk That's the magic of Ferrari :D

Answer (score 1):

As your code snippet does not have any `else` stetement, you can reduce your code to

```
 if (<condition1> && <condition2> && <condition3>)
```

and so on.

Comment: yes but I have many conditions like you wrote, checking different things which cannot be written together

Comment: @MasterYoda and how exactly is that? Can you show some example?

Comment: @MasterYoda: "*.. which cannot be written together*" why not? You might want to show the details if the details are relevant. This is not a guessing game.

Comment: @alk  I edited code, look now.

Comment: @MasterYoda As I Can see, there is nothing in your snippet that _cannot be done_ the suggested way. What did you try?

Comment: @SouravGhosh If I wrote all of that in one row, it will look big.

Comment: @MasterYoda I don't think your compiler bothers about that. :-) From the point of human readibility, I agree, that is _bad_, but not as you said _"which cannot be written together"_.

Comment: @MasterYoda: Group the conditions in a manner that makes sense and add line-breaks to seperate such groups.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, but in case of not so big memories and weak processors, I think that these things are so much important.

Comment: @MasterYoda you are confused. The changes in formatting most people are proposing, as they have told you many times, do not change the size of code generated, nor the amount of memory it uses. Same code. Just different formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont have else clause associated with if, just and all condition together like:

```
if (thisCondition && thatCondition ..) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If variables `a`, `b`, `c` are declared `unsigned`, that'll reduce an `if`.
2. If specific else blocks are not present, two if statements can be merged

You can then reduce your code to

```
unsigned a, b, c;    // if declared as unsigned or if d, e, f are known to be positive

if (a == d && b == e && c == f && a < FIELD_HEIGHT && b < FIELD_WIDTH) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377859/many-conditions-reducing-code-size?noredirect=1#comment50734732_31377892):

```
if (   (a>0 && a<FIELD_HEIGHT && a==d)
    && (b>0 && b<FIELD_WIDTH && b==e)
    && (c>0 && c==f)
   )
{
  ...
}
```

and assuming the varibales were `unsigned` integers:

```
if (   (a && a<FIELD_HEIGHT && a==d)
    && (b && b<FIELD_WIDTH && b==e)
    && (c && c==f)
   )
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ok：

```
if(a>0 && b>0 && c>0) 
{
    if(a==d && b==e && c==f)
    {
         if(a<FIELD_HEIGHT && b<FIELD_WIDTH)
         {

         }
    }
}
```

in your code, the last judgment:"if(true)" is redundant